# Buck/boost converter (XL6019) produces wrong output voltage when powerbank goes less than 5v

Tags: power-supply, voltage, buck-boost

I recently bought a buck/boost converter ([XL6019](http://www.xlsemi.com/datasheet/XL6019%20datasheet-English.pdf)), and I was trying to boost to 9 V to power a device (RC Car).

My idea was to use a power bank instead of 6 x 1.5 V AA batteries, but I realized that when my power bank is not fully charged (below 5 V), my boost goes up to much more than 9 V, reaching around 40 V; this doesn't occur with a steady 5 V power supply.

Is this behavior to be expected, or is my converter (or power bank) having issues? I thought it was possible to use a power bank with a boost converter, but if the output voltage goes up much more than the set voltage when the input drops below 5 V, this becomes impossible.

If expected, is there anything that can be done to protect the output from overvoltage? Or are buck/boost converters not really recommended for use with batteries?

**Edit**: the "XL6019" I have is a chinese module, identical to [this one](https://satoshinm.github.io/blog/180224_xl6019dcdc_xl6019_boost_buck_dc_dc_converter_unboxing.html), so I don't exactly have a schematic of it, if that's what you want.

About my circuit, I'm connecting the powerbank directly to its input, and the multimeter on the output... I believe I don't need a drawing for that.

Comment: It's all in the solidity and sophistication of the design. Bad ones can pull your pants down big time. Good ones hand you back your trousers.

Comment: Of course you can use buck/boost converters with batteries.  This is commonly done.  We would need to see some *datasheets* and *schematics* before we could even begin troubleshooting your problem.

Comment: This being Stackexchange, **edit your question** to include the datasheets of the parts you are using, and a schematic that shows how they're connected (or a picture or block diagram if you don't know how to do schematics -- but if the latter, expect help refining them if we can't make them out).

Comment: More information needed to diagnose your problem, but a guess says that you are not drawing enough current for that particular converter..

Comment: Many regulators require a minimum load current before the regulation loop can function as intended. Connect a load resistor to draw (guess) 10mA - from 9V, just try 1kilohm - and see if the regulation problem goes away.

Answer (score 4):

Add a minimum load of something like 10-15mA and it should work properly. There is a minimum amount of energy passed to the output on each pulse, and this particular part does not have a pulse-skipping feature, though it does have UVLO.

Comment: I tried to add a load with a 1 k ohm resistor and it didn't work, seems like this module doesn't have undervolt protection.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have any information on the XL6019 module then it is unknown how it works. Don't buy unknown stuff.

However, since you know it uses the XL6019 chip, the [datasheet](http://www.xlsemi.com/datasheet/XL6019%20datasheet-English.pdf) of the chip will help.

The XL6019 chip has a minimum of 5.0V input voltage, so it does not work with voltages below 5.0V. So yes, this is expected behaviour - anything can happen when voltage goes below 5.0V.

And the module you bought is so badly designed that it does not implement an undervoltage lockout mechanism to turn off the chip when the input voltage is not enough to work properly.

Comment: You're right, I tried to add a minimal load to the circuit and it still doesn't work, better not to use batteries with this module.